# How to XOR char array with an integer in C

Tags: c, xor

I am trying to implement a cryptographic algorithm in C. I have an unsigned char array;

```
 unsigned char ciphertext[] = { 0xA5, 0xB2, 0x3C, 0xAB, 0x03, 0xF1, 0xD3, 0x1C, 0x7F, 0xAD, 0x37, 0xA8, 0x8C, 0x8B, 0xCD, 0x90, 0xD4, 0xC2, 0x30, 0xAB, 0xD2, 0x3F, 0x3D, 0xAF, 0x58, 0x94, 0x1F, 0x50, 0xAF, 0xA2, 0xCE, 0x01 };
```

I need to XOR the char array with all values from 1 to 256. How can I do it in C? Thank you in advance.
 EDİT:
  I want to XOR my char array with;

```
unsigned char [] = { 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01};
unsigned char two = { 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02};
unsigned char three[] = { 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03};
```

And so on... That is the reason why I can not xor through each elements. It would be something different.

Comment: loop through the array and use the `^` xor operator..?

Comment: No the post is about two integers.  If I loop through the array, each elements of  the array will xor with 1 ( for example).

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    cryptotext[i] = ciphertext[i] ^ (i%256);
}
```

Note that you can use only one array if you don't want to keep you plain text:

```
ciphertext[i] ^= (i%256);
```

Comment: But in this case, I xor all the elements by 1..256 if I am not wrong.  For example; I can represent 1 as `unsigned char one[] = { 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01};` , So I think I can xor these two array. However, I  do not know how I can increment the array by 1.

Comment: Here you just XOR byte by byte through the whole array. I don't get your comment, could you please clarify what you want? Maybe a sample input/output in your question would help.

Comment: Yes, I apologize for my bad clarification, I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

XOR performs the following operations. please see below.

```
x   y    XOR
------------
0   0     0
1   0     1
0   1     1
1   1     0
```

You can't xor the entire array in one piece. you need to loop through the array and transform it character by character.

perform loop through the array and perform the XOR Operation.